Xcode downloads client crash report but the stacktraces don't contain any of my app's symbols
All the threads only contain system calls. The crashed thread only contains a single call to my app's code which is main.swift:12.
What could cause such a crash?
Process:               MyApp [83642]
Path:                  /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
Identifier:            org.example.myApp
Version:               3.16 (117)
App Item ID:           583995251
App External ID:       867849851
Code Type:             ARM-64
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2024-08-05 11:56:54.7371 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 14.5 (23F79)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        66B35603-13F2-2F39-6CAE-2ED04ECE96F6

Sleep/Wake UUID:       8C02FBE4-E0F4-4B6D-9C9F-DA2E5776046A

Time Awake Since Boot: 630000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       7670 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process:   MyApp [83642]


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018c71ea60 __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c756c20 pthread_kill + 288 (pthread.c:1721)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018c663a30 abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018c70dd08 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:78)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018c6fdfc0 demangling_terminate_handler() + 348 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:77)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018c39c1d0 _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:496)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018c70d0cc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018c70d070 std::terminate() + 108 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c5a63fc _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:579)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c5b4bb8 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 988 (queue.c:7898)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c5b47cc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44 (queue.c:8058)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c877ad4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1780)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c835258 __CFRunLoopRun + 1996 (CFRunLoop.c:3149)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c834434 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
14  HIToolbox                       0x0000000196fd819c RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292 (EventLoop.c:455)
15  HIToolbox                       0x0000000196fd7fd8 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 648 (EventBlocking.c:384)
16  HIToolbox                       0x0000000196fd7d30 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76 (EventBlocking.c:171)
17  AppKit                          0x0000000190093d68 _DPSNextEvent + 660 (CGDPSReplacement.m:810)
18  AppKit                          0x0000000190889808 -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 700 (appEventRouting.m:413)
19  AppKit                          0x000000019008709c -[NSApplication run] + 476 (NSApplication.m:3513)
20  AppKit                          0x000000019005e2e0 NSApplicationMain + 880 (NSApplication.m:10138)
21  MyApp                           0x0000000100dc9670 main + 128 (main.swift:12)
22  dyld                            0x000000018c3ce0e0 start + 2360 (dyldMain.cpp:1298)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018c7161f4 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018c728b24 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018c71ee34 mach_msg_overwrite + 476 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018c716578 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c836680 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c834f44 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c834434 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   AppKit                          0x00000001901be188 _NSEventThread + 144 (NSEvent.m:5569)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c756f94 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:931)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c751d34 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018c7161f4 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018c728b24 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018c71ee34 mach_msg_overwrite + 476 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018c716578 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   QuartzCore                      0x0000000194a6c0ec CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 580 (render-server.cpp:735)
5   QuartzCore                      0x0000000194a6be98 thread_fun(void*) + 32 (x-thread.cpp:29)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c756f94 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:931)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c751d34 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018c7161f4 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018c728b24 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018c71ee34 mach_msg_overwrite + 476 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018c716578 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c836680 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c834f44 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c834434 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c8b245c CFRunLoopRun + 64 (CFRunLoop.c:3446)
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8d342cc ***::Detail::CallableWrapper::call() + 52 (Function.h:53)
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8d57758 ***::Thread::entryPoint(***::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 244 (Threading.cpp:258)
10  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8b9a120 ***::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:243)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c756f94 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:931)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c751d34 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c751d20 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018c7199ec __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c75755c _pthread_cond_wait + 1228 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001aa0e3c70 scavenger_thread_main + 1512 (pas_scavenger.c:347)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c756f94 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:931)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c751d34 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018c751d20 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000018c7122cb   x5: 0x000000016f03a350   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0xad040d6a4cc50bd3   x9: 0xad040d6bb89c07d3  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x00000000001ff800  x14: 0x00000000000007fb  x15: 0x00000000bf41086f
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001fe945928  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001f4590c00  x21: 0x0000000000000103  x22: 0x00000001f4590ce0  x23: 0x0000000000000114
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x00000001f4590ce0  x26: 0x0000600001c60000  x27: 0x000000000000000f
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016f03a2c0   lr: 0x000000018c756c20
    sp: 0x000000016f03a2a0   pc: 0x000000018c71ea60 cpsr: 0x40001000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault


Binary Images:
        0x100dc4000 -         0x100ef3fff MyApp (arm64)  <FF97590B-54A0-39DE-86A5-C7AA2F6117E2> /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
        0x156640000 -         0x15664bfff libobjc-trampolines.dylib (arm64e)  <9381BD6D-84A5-3C72-B3B8-88428AFA4782> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
        0x15bf04000 -         0x15bf0bfff FileProviderOverride (arm64e)  <48C78787-AEBF-3B9C-8300-2B20BA87B0A4> /System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FileProviderOverride
        0x160948000 -         0x16094bfff iCloudDriveFileProviderOverride (arm64e)  <DB39A641-8C34-385D-8FAF-37CB3DCFC89E> /System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/iCloudDriveFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/iCloudDriveFileProviderOverride
        0x1609a8000 -         0x1609c7fff FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride (arm64e)  <45B63A1F-97C2-3047-9430-120757EC26F6> /System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride
        0x161974000 -         0x161993fff csparser (arm64e)  <5B38C00E-20A2-3DD5-B582-3D7BF058F0BA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/PlugIns/csparser.bundle/Contents/MacOS/csparser
        0x162c14000 -         0x162c7ffff AppleMetalOpenGLRenderer (arm64e)  <C032830A-FBED-356D-A4A7-ACD24492F336> /System/Library/Extensions/AppleMetalOpenGLRenderer.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleMetalOpenGLRenderer
        0x18c378000 -         0x18c3c7d83 libobjc.A.dylib (arm64e)  <B326B2C3-1069-3D17-B49D-9DCB24EFEC6F> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
        0x18c3c8000 -         0x18c450a17 dyld (arm64e)  <37BBC384-0755-31C7-A808-0ED49E44DD8E> /usr/lib/dyld
        0x18c5a2000 -         0x18c5e9fff libdispatch.dylib (arm64e)  <502762EE-7AA7-306C-9DBD-88981A86BB78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
        0x18c5ed000 -         0x18c66bff7 libsystem_c.dylib (arm64e)  <05B44E93-DFFC-3BD8-90AB-FD97CB73F171> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
        0x18c6f9000 -         0x18c714ffb libc++abi.dylib (arm64e)  <4AC7C5CD-3746-3A53-AAD6-C231E183B705> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
        0x18c715000 -         0x18c74fffb libsystem_kernel.dylib (arm64e)  <9B8B53F9-E2B6-36DF-98E9-28D8FCA732F2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
        0x18c750000 -         0x18c75cfff libsystem_pthread.dylib (arm64e)  <386B0FC1-7873-3328-8E71-43269FD1B2C7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
        0x18c7b8000 -         0x18cc90fff CoreFoundation (arm64e)  <84B539D5-22C9-3F8C-84C8-903E9C7B8D29> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
        0x18d90d000 -         0x18e56afff Foundation (arm64e)  <99E0292D-7873-3968-9C9C-5955638689A5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
        0x19005a000 -         0x191396fff AppKit (arm64e)  <61F710BE-9132-3CC2-883D-066365FBA1AD> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
        0x194a24000 -         0x194dd3fff QuartzCore (arm64e)  <5B8CEDA1-6957-3595-9775-333DDE684699> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
        0x196fa5000 -         0x197268fff HIToolbox (arm64e)  <7DB6C397-563F-3756-908C-E25B019A1848> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
        0x1a8b92000 -         0x1aa2b9f1f JavaScriptCore (arm64e)  <C2B56B65-EF15-316A-B19F-24510E5D0846> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/JavaScriptCore
        0x31a038000 -         0x31a917fff AudioCodecs (arm64e)  <10DC413B-3923-3F80-8A3D-35AACAAA801E> /System/Library/Components/AudioCodecs.component/Contents/MacOS/AudioCodecs


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.4G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.4G(100%)
Writable regions: Total=1.8G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.8G(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               256K        2 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CG image                          3200K      118 
ColorSync                          736K       38 
CoreAnimation                     10.9M      177 
CoreGraphics                        32K        2 
CoreImage                           48K        3 
CoreUI image data                 3024K       44 
Foundation                          48K        2 
Image IO                            16K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                 4144K        2 
MALLOC                             1.6G       55 
MALLOC guard page                  192K       12 
STACK GUARD                       56.1M        7 
Stack                             11.7M        7 
VM_ALLOCATE                        304K       15 
WebKit Malloc                    160.1M        5 
WebKit Malloc (reserved)          32.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__AUTH                            3533K      487 
__AUTH_CONST                      37.2M      716 
__CTF                               824        1 
__DATA                            19.0M      707 
__DATA_CONST                      37.3M      729 
__DATA_DIRTY                      2184K      258 
__FONT_DATA                        2352        1 
__GLSLBUILTINS                    5174K        1 
__INFO_FILTER                         8        1 
__LINKEDIT                       534.7M        9 
__OBJC_RO                         71.9M        2 
__OBJC_RW                         2199K        1 
__TEXT                           852.3M      749 
dyld private memory                272K        2 
mapped file                      959.2M      295 
shared memory                      864K       14 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              4.3G     4465 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     4.3G     4465 


EOF

